# Slide content animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: slide content]

This is my content and different content has different behaviour such as when the **1st column click column 2, column 3, column 4 move to right** and if **4th column click it push all the content to left**.

Jquery

```
$("#toogle-1").click(function () {
    $(".WSUA__column__two").animate({ left: '50%' });
    $(".WSUA__column__three").animate({ right: '-25%' });
    $(".WSUA__column__four").animate({ right: '-50%' });
    $("span.hidden-menu.toogle-1").show();
    $("div.hidden-cross.toogle-1").show();
    $("#toogle-1").hide();
    $("#toogle-2").addClass("unclickable");
    $("#toogle-3").addClass("unclickable");
    $("#toogle-4").addClass("unclickable");
});
$("div.hidden-cross.toogle-1").click(function () {
    $(".WSUA__column__two").animate({ left: '25%' });
    $(".WSUA__column__three").animate({ right: '0%' });
    $(".WSUA__column__four").animate({ right: '-25%' });
    $(".hidden-menu").hide();
    $("div.hidden-cross.toogle-1").hide();
    $("#toogle-1").show();
    $("#toogle-2").removeClass("unclickable");
    $("#toogle-3").removeClass("unclickable");
    $("#toogle-4").removeClass("unclickable");
});
```

[image: column 1]

Is there any way to create a function without declare toogle-1, toogle-2, toogle-3, and toogle-4? Let's say i want to create another content like this and i have to duplicate all the jquery and change all the toogle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.container > div:nth-child(odd)').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).nextAll().toggleClass('siblings-move-odd');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active-odd');
   });
   jQuery('.container > div:nth-child(even)').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).prevAll().toggleClass('siblings-move-even');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('active-even');
   });
  });
```

```css
   .container {
   }
   .container > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    transition: left 1s ease-in;
    left: 0;
   }
   .container > div.siblings-move-odd {
    left: 25%;
    transition: left 1s ease-in;
   }
   .container > div.siblings-move-even {
    left: -25%;
    transition: left 1s ease-in;
   }
   .container div .right {
    background: grey;
    height: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    display: inline-block; 
    position: absolute;
    transition: width 1s ease-in;
   }
   .container div:nth-child(odd) .right {
    left: 100%;
   }
   .container div:nth-child(even) .right {
    right: 100%;
   }
   .container > div.active-odd .right {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 1s ease-in;
   }
   .container > div.active-even .right {
    width: 100%;
    transition: width 1s ease-in;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div style="background-color: red;">
    1
    <div class="right">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background-color: blue;">
    2
    <div class="right">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background-color: green;">
    3
    <div class="right">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div style="background-color: purple;">
    4
    <div class="right">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```